# Ember-cli: Stop or restart server

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Is there a quick way to stop or restart the server in `ember-cli`? Specially, when you've hit an error and need to restart it. Currently, I just close the window and reopen it, but that gets tedious when I'm making large changes to my `Brocfile.js` and such. Thanks.

Comment: Yup, CTRL+C, CTRL+Z, ESC; none seemed to work. I'm on Windows if that makes any difference.

Comment: Through command prompt.

Comment: There was a bug I was encountering on Mac OSX where CTRL-C was not working properly to stop the server. It went away at some point due to an upgrade. If possible, try upgrading ember-cli.

Comment: I'm not sure what happen, but `CTRL+C` does stop the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it's important to note that This has nothing to do with ember.js or ember CLI. This is an issue with your terminal.

control + C

*will* terminate the current process in your terminal shell.

If it doesn't, then you should be checking your OS, or the type of terminal you are using.

Comment: as of 05/2015, this ember autoserve addon is pretty great for this type of case: https://github.com/ebryn/ember-autoserve - it's goal is to restart your server for you in case something large like your cli file changes etc.